# how can I store and send some images (pictures) in Hyperledger Smart Contract?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, smartcontracts

I want to know how to store and send as a transaction some picture or link to some resources in Hyperledged Smart Contract.

Where in code I should do it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

The chaincode function to store data to blockchain in a Hyperledger Fabric chaincode is:

```
    PutState(key string, value []byte)
```

The value can be any byte array, which may represent a picture to store on the blockchain, or a link to a resource outside the blockchain.